# Binding on RotateTransform Angle in DataTemplate not taking effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my WPF UserControl I have this resource, please observe the comments in the Xml sample.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AxisXLabelTemplate">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
            <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding XAxisLabelRotation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> <!-- This does not work -->
                <!-- <RotateTransform Angle="-90" /> This works -->
            </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the code I have a dependency property defined as follows:

```
class MyChart: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty XAxisLabelRotationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("XAxisLabelRotation", typeof(RotateTransform), typeof(BarChart),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((RotateTransform)new RotateTransform(-90.0)));

        public RotateTransform XAxisLabelRotation
        {
            get { return (RotateTransform)GetValue(XAxisLabelRotationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(XAxisLabelRotationProperty, value); }
        }
...
}
```

The AxisXLabelTemplate DataTemplate is assigned to an element farther below as follows:

```
<chart:AxisLabel ElementTemplate="{StaticResource AxisXLabelTemplate}"/>
```

The problem is that when I use the unbound value for Angle and hard-code it to -90, it works beautifully, and when I try with the bound value to XAxisLabelRotation it doesn't.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: And did you look for any binding errors (output window) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreated similar setting as you and it did not work for me either. Curiously there are no binding errors. I did relativesource binding too and it didnt work.

Although if I bind tooltip

```
  <ContentPresenter ToolTip="{Binding XAxisLabelRotation, 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                          AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ..>
```

shows the tooltip to me. So I changed the rotate transform,

```
  <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding XAxisLabelRotation, 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                          AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ..>
```

But still the transform did not work. Still no binding errors.

Then I introduced a dummy converter ...

```
public class AngleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(...)
    {
        return value;
    }
    ....
}

<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding XAxisLabelRotation, 
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                      AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                 Converter={StaticResource AngleConverter}}" ..>
```

and it worked miraculously!!!

Unexplanable world of WPF???

Comment: All I had to do was add ElementName=... with the name I gave to the root element of the data context I wanted to bind to (in my case, the UserControl that my element was residing in). I guess the DataContext is different for a RotateTransform inside an element :\ Either way, no need for the dummy converter and UpdateSourceTrigger in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the angle like this:

```
<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/476d9418-8d9c-447a-95a4-37162740d095/template-binding-problem?forum=wpf)

Comment: It works in my case (I was trying to template-bind RenderTransform Angle inside ControlTemplate). Looks like template binding does not apply to attached properties.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `DataContext` correct? If this rotation is part of the `Content` you bound to earlier you either need to change the `DataContext` or add that to the binding path of the rotation, i.e. make it `{Binding Content.XAxisLabelRotation}`.

Do you know how to debug bindings? As you did not present any binding errors i would assume you do not, so if this is the case please read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) and make sure that you do provide the errors if you cannot debug a binding yourself in the future.